# Integral form of Euler characteristic

Tags: differential-topology

There is a known formula for Euler characteristic in terms of Ricci scalar:
\begin{equation}
\chi(M)=\frac{1}{4\pi} \int_M \sqrt{g} \,R\,d^2x\,.
\end{equation}
I am sure that this formula holds for two dimensional manifolds, but what about higher dimensional ones? What integral can define Euler characteristic in higher dimensions?

Answer (score 6):

You want the [Chern-Gauss-Bonnet theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem). See also [Chern-Weil theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chern%E2%80%93Weil_homomorphism).

Comment: Links may be useful but explain something as a hint to OP. Can you please add some more details?

Comment: @Bhaskara: the details are all in the links. On a closed oriented Riemannian manifold of dimension $2n$ there is a particular $2n$-form you can write down, which is a fairly explicit function of the curvature $2$-form, whose integral gives the Euler characteristic. There's even an example given when $n = 2$.